# The distribution of a sum of squared Gamma random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Random variable $X$ is a sum of $N$ squared Gamma RVs as:
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i^2$$
where $X_i\sim Gam(k,\theta_i)$, the shape parameter $k$ is not an integer and scale parameters $\theta_i, \forall i$ may be distinct values.

As I know there are several results for the PDF/CDF of a sum of gamma RVs (iid or non iid), but I could not find any literature related to this problem.

If anyone knows a solution for the PDF/CDF of $X$, please share with me.

Comment: $X_i^2$ will have a generalised gamma distribution so you can find its mean and variance, and thus the mean and variance of their sum $X$.  Would a CLT-type result (assuming the $\theta_i$ behave) meet your needs?

Comment: In my case, $N$ is mostly less than $10$.

Answer (score 1):

The square of the Gamma is a generalized gamma distribution.
The sum of generalized gamma distributions was studied in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4197204_On_the_Distribution_of_the_Sum_of_Generalized_Gamma_Variates_and_Applications_to_Satellite_Digital_Communications/link/02e7e51d95c310d34c000000/download

Comment: It is an upper bound only.